# Implementing custom client-side load balancing policy in hornetq

Tags: java, hornetq

I want to implement a load balancing policy in HornetQ that depends on the IP Addresses of the nodes. For example, if a specified node is available connect it to it, otherwise connect to a random node.
However, the ConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy interface only gives me the input as a number

```
int select (int max);
```

Let's assume that the max is three, I want to know the IP Address of 0,1,2 before selecting the node. Is that possible?

It is written in that section in HornetQ documentation:

> The set of servers over which the factory load balances can be
>   determined in one of two ways:
>
> ```
> Specifying servers explicitly
>
> Using discovery.
> ```

So how can I get them using discovery and match them to the max number I get from ConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy ?

Thanks,
Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom Load Balancer at the Client's ServerLocator by doing

```
ServerLocator locator = ....

locator.setConnectionLoadBalancingPolicyClassName("YOUR-CLASS-NAME);
```

However the current version doesn't allow you access at the topology array.

We should change our implementation to send the topologyArray to the select method. If you open a JIRA we will take care of that.